# implement `each` for Enumerable mixin in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module, block, enumerable

I'm learning about the magic of Enumerable in Ruby. I've heard one have to just include `Enumerable` and implement `each` method and can have the power of Enumerable for that class.

So, I thought about implementing my own custom class Foo for practice. It looks like below:

```
class Foo
  include Enumerable

  def initialize numbers
    @num = numbers
  end

  def each
    return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?
    @num.each { |i| yield i + 1 }
  end
end
```

This class takes an array and its `each` works almost similar to `Array#each`. Here's the difference:

```
>> f = Foo.new [1, 2, 3]
=> #<Foo:0x00000001632e40 @num=[1, 2, 3]>
>> f.each { |i| p i }
2
3
4
=> [1, 2, 3]   # Why this? Why not [2, 3, 4]?
```

Everything works like I expect except one thing which is the last statement. I know its the return value but shouldn't it be `[2, 3, 4]`. Is there a way to make it `[2, 3, 4]`.

Also please comment on the way I have implemented `each`. If there's a better way please let me know. At first in my implementation I didn't had this line `return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?` and then it wasn't working when no block was provided. I borrowed this line from somewhere and also please tell me whether this is the right way to handle the situation or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `each` is supposed to be the receiver, i.e. `self`. But you are returning the result of calling `@num.each`. Now, as I just said, `each` returns `self`, ergo `@num.each` returns `@num`.

The fix is simple: just return `self`:

```
def each
  return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?
  @num.each { |i| yield i + 1 }
  self
end
```

Or, possibly a bit more Rubyish:

```
def each
  return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?
  tap { @num.each { |i| yield i + 1 }}
end
```

[Actually, as of Ruby 1.8.7+, `each` is also supposed to return an `Enumerator` when called without a block, but you are already correctly handling that. Tip: if you want to implement optimized versions of some of the other `Enumerable` methods by overriding them, or want to add your own `Enumerable`-like methods with similar behavior, as the original ones, you are going to cut&paste that exact same line of code over and over, and at one point, you will accidentally forget to change the name of the method. If you replace the line with `return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?`, you don't have to remember changing the name.]

Answer (score 2):

`each` does not modify an array. If you want to return modified array, use `map`:

```
def each
  return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?
  @num.map { |i| yield i + 1 }
end
f.each { |i| p i }
2
3
4
=> [2, 3, 4]
```

But I recommend to use each inside a custom method. You can increment each element of your array by 1 in `initialize` method, since you want to use it for all calculations. Also, you can modify your `each` method to avoid using `enum_for` by passing `block_given?` inside a block. Finally your code will look like:

```
class Foo
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(numbers)
    @num = numbers.map {|n| n + 1 }
  end

  def each
    @num.each { |i| yield i if block_given? }
  end
end

f = Foo.new [1, 2, 3]
=> #<Foo:0x00000000f8e0d0 @num=[2, 3, 4]>
f.each { |i| p i }
2
3
4
=> [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: With `yield(i+1) if block_given?` I get wrong result for f.each

Comment: @Lokesh, maybe you missed some code. Please, see on current version of answer

Comment: I really like your first solution. The second solution which you have suggested which is to change initialize doesn't fit into my need because instead of (i+1) I have something like ('abc' * i) which occupies space, so changing @num before hand would take upon more space than necessary.

Comment: @Lokesh, no problem, put it into each: `@num.map {|i| i + 1}.each { |i| yield i if block_given? }`. It is just an instance, direction, you are an engineer, so combine solutions!)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `map` instead of `each`.

```
f.map { |i| p i }
#=> [2,3,4]
```

The fact that `Foo` includes `Enumerable` means that all the methods of `Enumerable` can be invoked on instances of `Foo`

Comment: Hi. The issue is I want my custom `each` to behave just like normal `each`.

Comment: @Lokesh it does behave like an normal `each`. That is, Array behaves the same. I makes method chaining possible. `map` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

> This class takes an array and its each works almost similar to `Array#each`.
>
> I know its the return value but shouldn't it be [2, 3, 4].

1. A def returns the result of the last statement that was executed.
2. `Array#each` returns the original array.

Applying those rules to your def:

```
def each
  return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?
  @num.each { |i| yield i + 1 }  #Array#each returns @num
end  #When a block is given, the result of the last statement that was executed is @num
```

You could always do something like this:

```
class Foo
  include Enumerable

  def initialize numbers
    @num = numbers
    @enum_vals = []
  end

  def each
    if block_given?
      @num.each do |i| 
        yield i + 1
        @enum_vals << i + 1
      end

      @enum_vals
    else
      enum_for
    end
  end
end

result = Foo.new([1, 2, 3, ]).each {|i| p i}
p result

--output:--
2
3
4
[2, 3, 4]
```